# Limit problem: "dividing by zero"

Tags: limits

I'm trying to find a unique formula, but I can't seem to manage this limit. It might be impossible, but I thought it was worth a shot asking here.
The expression is the following;

$$\frac {-4b^4c^3+4a^2b^2c^3+ab^4c^2\ln\frac{a+c}{a-c}-ab^4c^2\ln\frac{a-c}{a+c}}{2a^6-2a^4c^2}$$
What I need, is to take the limit as $c$ approaches $a$. I hope someone might be able to solve it or hint me in the right direction. But as I said, it might be unsolvable.

Comment: Are you familiar with l'hopitals rule.  If you get $\frac 00$ when you plug in $c=a$ then treat $c$ as a variable and differentiate the numerater and denominator in terms of $c$.

Comment: I've heard of it, but never fully understood it. What do you do after differentiating? Also, do you differentiate the numerator and the denominator by themselves?

Comment: Well, my first thought is you would but that's not actually the case here and it does not apply.

Comment: Ah, ok. Well thanks for the idea at least!

Comment: You use L'hopitals rules when you have $\lim blah$ is of the from $\lim \frac {f(c)}{g(c)}$ and when you plug it $c=a$ you "get"  $\frac 00$ or $\frac {\infty}{\infty}$.  This is what is referred to as "indeterminate form" Depending on how "fast" the numerator and denominator go to $0$ or infty the value *could* be anything... so "indeterminate". But as it depends on how fast  (i.e the derivative) $\lim \frac {f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim \frac {f'(x)}{g'(x)}$.  so for example $\lim_x\to 0 \frac {e^x -1}{x} = \lim {[e^x-1]'}{[x]}=\lim\frac {e^x}{1} = \frac {e^0}1 = 1$. !!!BUT!!!!! to be continued.....

Comment: .... cont.... !!!!BUT!!!! you can only do it if $\frac {f(x)}{g(x)}$ is in $\frac 00$ or $\frac {\pm \infty}{\pm \infty}$ form.  If it is is $\frac {\infty}c$ or $\frac {\infy}0$ or some other form you can't use it.  In this case you can't use it as you have $\frac {stuff + \ln \infty -\ln 0}{0}$ which although it is in "undefined" form is not in "indeterminate" form.... to be continued.

Comment: ... cont... perhaps the most common novice mistake is to confuse "undefined" with "indeterminate".  Undefined means it can't be anything (such as $\frac 10$);  If $\frac 10 = x$ then $0\cdot x = 1$ and that's impossible) but  indeterminate means it could be anything.  )Such as $\frac 00$; (if $\frac 00 = x$ then $0\cdot x = 0$ and that is not just possible, it is inevitable $x=0$ is a solution; $x=7$ is a solutions $x = \frac 1{\sqrt \pi}$ is a solution.

Comment: Ok, well that makes sense. Thanks for clarifying the rule for me!

Answer (score 0):

$\frac {-4b^4c^3 + 4a^2b^2c^3 + ab^4c^2\ln \frac{a+c}{a-c} -ab^4c^2\ln\frac {a-c}{a+c}}{2a^6 -2a^4c^2}=$

$\frac {-4b^4c^3 + 4a^2b^2c^3 + ab^4c^2[\ln\frac {a+c}{a-c} - \ln \frac {a-c}{a+c}]}{2a^6 -2a^4c^2}=$

$\frac {-4b^4c^3 + 4a^2b^2c^3 + ab^4c^2[\ln\frac {\frac {a+c}{a-c}}{\frac {a-c}{a+c}}]}{2a^6 -2a^4c^2}=$

$\frac {-4b^4c^3 + 4a^2b^2c^3 + ab^4c^2[\ln(\{\frac {a+c}{a-c}\}^2)]}{2a^6 -2a^4c^2}=$

$\frac {-4b^4c^3 + 4a^2b^2c^3 + 2ab^4c^2[\ln(\frac {a+c}{a-c})]}{2a^6 -2a^4c^2}=$

$\frac {-4b^4c^3 + 4a^2b^2c^3 + 2ab^4c^2\ln( {a+c}) -2ab^4c^2\ln({a-c})}{2a^6 -2a^4c^2}=$

Now if we plug in $a=c$ (the expression is continuous so that it is allowed) we ge $\ln (a-c) = \ln 0$ is undefined (but approaches $-\infty$) and $2a^6 - 2a^4c^2 = 0$. The rest of the terms all approach finite and negligatibe values. SO the expression of the limit is of the form

$\frac {\infty}{0}$.  Or to be or accurate the limit of $\frac {BIG}{small}$ where as $a\to c$ we have $BIG\to \infty$ and and $a\to c$ we have $small\to 0$.

So $\lim_{a\to c}\frac {-4b^4c^3 + 4a^2b^2c^3 + ab^4c^2\ln \frac{a+c}{a-c} -ab^4c^2\ln\frac {a-c}{a+c}}{2a^6 -2a^4c^2}=\infty$.

Comment: I see; well thanks again. In theory, it should work based on where I got it from, but I guess not. Thanks again for attempting to help.

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  No, in theory it should work and it does and this is the result.  And what do you mean "attempting to help".  This *IS* the solution.

Comment: Yeah, no sorry. What I meant was that I thought it would've converged, based on where I got it from. I have no doubt that what you did was the answer,  I'm just a bit perplexed as to where to head now.